# Finding best case, worst case, and average case for an unknown algorithm

Tags: algorithms, computer-science

I have been given a paragraph explaining what an unknown algorithm does:

> An algorithm checks to see if a list of integers is sorted, it starts at the beginning of the list, and scans along until a successive pair of elements is out of order. In this case, the algorithm returns false. In other cases(i.e. the list of integers is sorted) the algorithm would return true.

I have worked out that the worst case running time for this algorithm on an input list of n elements O(n). The best case running time for this algorithm on an input list with n elements is Ω(2). What would be the average-case expected running time be for an input list with a random permutation of numbers from 1,2...n? I'm really not sure if my answers are correct or not...

Comment: I don't think the best case is $\Omega(2)$.; it still has to look at the whole list.

Comment: The average-case running time depends on the distribution of the input. Anyway, in big O notation you can say it is $O(n)$ because it cannot exceed the worst case running time. But if you want big $\Theta$, you do need to know the input distribution.

Comment: @EricTressler I guess the OP means when the first three elements in the sequence are not sorted.

Comment: True; my fault.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the list is uniformly distributed, its $k$ first elements are ordered increasingly with probability $1/k!$ and they are ordered decreasingly with probability $1/k!$ hence the number $N$ of comparisons needed by the algorithm is such that $P[N\geqslant k]=2/k!$ for every $2\leqslant k\leqslant n-1$. Thus, for every $n\geqslant3$, one sees that $2\leqslant E[N]\leqslant2\mathrm e-3$, in particular $E[N]=\Theta(1)$.

Comment: My guess is that "sorted" is intended to mean "increasing".